# how to set methods name dynamically in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple tabs in a page,by clicking any of them I want to call a method:
HTML:

```
@foreach (Tabs tab in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Tabs)))
  {
    <uib-tab index="@((int)tab)">
        <uib-tab-heading ng-click="tabSelected('@tab')">
        </uib-tab-heading>
    </uib-tab>
  }
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.tabSelected = function (tab) {
        $scope[tab]();
      };
```

now I get Error said:  `$scope[tab]()` is not a function!
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think defining all functions before `$scope.tabSelected` is your answer.

Javascript works from top to bottom, so your functions must be delcared before this function.

```
$scope.x = function() {

};

$scope.y = function() {

};

$scope.z = function() {

};

$scope.tabSelected = function(tab) {
  $scope[tab]();
};
```

A working example:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("text", [
  "$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.x = function() {
      console.log("x");
    };

    $scope.y = function() {
      console.log("y");
    };

    $scope.z = function() {
      console.log("z");
    };

    $scope.tabSelected = function(tab) {
      $scope[tab]();
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="text">

    <button ng-click="tabSelected('x')">X</button>
    <button ng-click="tabSelected('y')">Y</button>
    <button ng-click="tabSelected('z')">Z</button>


  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odVwRY?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

your code should be:

```
$scope.tabSelected = function (tab) {
        $scope.selectedTab = tab;
      };
```